# Setting environment variable with WiX, losing filename at end of path

Tags: wix3.5

I am utilizing the WiX "Environment" element to set an environment variable.

```
<Environment Action="create" Name="My_Certificates" System="yes" Id="certificate_env" Value="[CERT_XML_PATH]" Permanent="yes" />
```

CERT_XML_PATH gets set to the following: c:\this\is\my\path\myfile.xml

If that file actually exists, the environment variable is set properly and points to the file. 
If that particular file doesn't exist at the time of the install, the environment variable is created and set, but the path is truncated to remove the myfile.xml portion.

This installer is part of a larger suite.  It has its own standalone MSI.  Installing one of the packages creates this xml file, but not the particular one I'm working on.  If the xml file has been created, everything works fine.  But if this installer is ran first, it will set the environment variable to

The environment variable "My_Certificates" gets created, but set to:

- c:\this\is\my\path\

Instead of:

- c:\this\is\my\path\myfile.xml

**Troubleshooting:**

The install log shows the property being set to the proper location.

MSI (s) (70:80) [15:27:44:988]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding CERT_XML_PATH property. Its value is 'c:\this\is\my\path\myfile.xml'.

Then we see the installer doing a WriteEnvironmentStrings a utilizing the proper path, including the xml file.

MSI (s) (70:80) [15:27:50:644]: Executing op: UpdateEnvironmentStrings(Name=My_Certificates,Value=c:\this\is\my\path\myfile.xml,Delimiter=[~],Action=536870914,)

WriteEnvironmentStrings: Name: My_Certificates, Value: c:\this\is\my\path\myfile.xml, Action 536870914

[screen shot of system variables showing it not set properly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Hptu.png)

Any insight into why the file name is being truncated would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm going to assume that you've used proper troubleshooting and made sure the environment variable is not there before running the install.

Otherwise I would think that it's only showing up in your current profile and logging out and back in again may show it correctly. Another idea is that something else is setting it to a different value.

Comment: You are correct that I am validating that the environment var does not exist before the install and that it does exist after the install.
I've also tried rebooting the machine after the install and logging back in and that did not resolve the issue. 
I'm also leaning towards something else setting that environment var and I just haven't been able to find it yet...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue.  There is a custom action in the installer that is also trying to set the Environment Variable.  When disabling that custom action, everything works as intended.